# Change values in matrix without loops in Matlab

Tags: arrays, matlab

I have an array where I want to change the values in certain columns according to an "indexing-array".

Suppose I have an array `A`, where the values in column 1 and 2 are to be switched according to the matrix `switch_mat`, below.

```
A(:,[1 2]) =         
 1     2    
 2     6
 2     7
 6     7
 7    12
 7    13
12    13

switch_mat =
 1     1
 2     2
 6     3
 7     4
12     5
13     6
```

Is it possible to do this *without loops*, using some functions like this?

```
A(:,[1 2]) = renum(A(:,[1 2]),switch_mat)
```

The new A matrix will be:

```
A(:,[1 2]) = 
 1     2    
 2     3
 2     4 
 3     4
 4     5
 4     6
 5     6
```

Thanks!

**EDIT:**
The switch in the A matrix will be:

```
1  -> 1
2  -> 2
6  -> 3
7  -> 4
12 -> 5
13 -> 6   % 13 becomes a 6, because they are in the same row of switch_mat
```

The dimension of `switch_mat = length(unique(A))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a possible solution with [`arrayfun`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/arrayfun.html):

```
A = arrayfun(@(x)switch_mat(switch_mat(:, 1) == x, 2), A);
```

Alternatively, you can use [`ismember`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/ismember.html):

```
[tf, loc] = ismember(A, switch_mat(:, 1));
A(loc > 0) = switch_mat(loc(loc > 0), 2);
```

I believe the latter method should be faster.