# How to change all matrix values according to a list

Tags: matlab, sparse-matrix

I have a 500x500 sparse matrix with values ranging from 0 to a.

I want to change its elements according to a list working as a dictionary. Elements that equal 1 become the value of list(1), that equal 2 become the value of list(2), etc until values that equal a become list(a)

Is there a simple way to do this?

Comment: [Related](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16750161/change-values-in-matrix-without-loops-in-matlab).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This can be done by at least three methods:

- method1

  ```
   [r, c, v] = find(m);
   m = sparse(r, c, list(v), size(m,1), size(m,2));
  ```
- method2

  ```
  m(find(m)) = list(nonzeros(m));
  ```
- method3

  ```
  m = spfun(@(x)list(x), m);
  ```

Answer (score 2):

Assuming your sparse matrix contains only integers between 0 and a, here is one way using logical indexing:

```
S = your sparse matrix
L = logical(S);  % mask of elements to replace
S(L) = list(S(L));  % replace mask elements with corresponding list elements
```